How can I ensure that generic argument types are different?
I have defined a trait (let's call it MyTrait) and implemented it for any type of tuple with two elements:
trait MyTrait {
  fn my_fn();
}

impl<T1, T2> MyTrait for (T1, T2) {
  fn my_fn() {...}
}

However, I would like to ensure that the trait is implemented only if T1 and T2 are different concrete types. E.g. (i32, i64) is ok, but (i32, i32) is not. This should also be extensible to larger tuples (up to 16 elements). Is there a way to do so?
I have tried using a static assertions in the following way:
fn my_fn() {
   static OK: () = assert!(std::any::TypeId::of::<T1>() != std::any::TypeId::of::<T2>());
   ...
}

This results in an error:
error[E0401]: can't use generic parameters from outer item

I guess this is because the value of OK would be shared by all implementations, no matter what T1 and T2 are concretely?
I have also tried thinking of ways to express this through trait bounds (which seems a more robust approach) but couldn't find a way.

Is this sort of what you're looking for? Looks like the trick is to implement a  marker trait on one. If the types are different the other generic param won't also get the same trait.

Pretty much I would like something like that, but it wouldn't work in my example because it wouldn't let me pass T1 and T2 as parameter to the macro (same error as in the example above). :)

So in other words, my problem would be how could I use static_assertions::assert_type_ne_all() together with generic arguments in the example above without incurring into error:
error[E0401]: can't use generic parameters from outer item

You can work around the "gneric parameters from outer item" error using the trick described here, and from 1.79 onward, just with const { assert_eq!(...) } (former implemented here). Sadly, then you run into TypeId::of() not yet being const, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Yep, I have experimented a bit in that direction, but indeed got blocked by the fact that TypeId::of isn't a const function... I guess the only "solution" for now is doing a runtime check? :(

Maybe just use debug_assert!() to catch issues where the types must be different during test and development. These asserts won't be included in release builds.

Use debug_assert!() and Add :'static, i.e, impl<T1: 'static, T2: 'static> MyTrait for (T1, T2)

@cafce25 Shouldn't the assertion use assert_ne!() rather than assert_eq!(), though? Or am I missing something?

@cafce25 That's quite surprising! Indeed, in this code, the assertion fails without the function actually being "instantiated", and it fails both with == and != in the assertion expression. Possible compiler bug?

@cafce25 I see what you mean - the compiler attempts to "check" the assertion prior to monomorphization for all possible types. But then how come checks like assert!(std::mem::size_of::<T>() != 0), shown here seem to work? Is that a bug?

Wait, that's all a red herring PartialEq for TypeId is not const, therfore TypeId::of::<T1>() == TypeId::of::<T2>() (or !=) is not valid inside a const context. I've opened an issue about a similar error message yesterday. The error message is just atrocious.

This is not really supported right now since TypeId::of is not const and even if it was, PartialEq for TypeId isn't const either.
If you're willing to use a nightly compiler with #![feature(const_type_id)] enabled and rely on the implementation details of TypeId, you can do the following:
#![feature(const_type_id)]
use std::any::TypeId;
use std::mem;
trait MyTrait {
    fn my_fn();
}

impl<T1: 'static, T2: 'static> MyTrait for (T1, T2) {
    fn my_fn() {
        const {
            // if `PartailEq for TypeId` was const this would be as easy as
            // assert!(TypeId::of::<T1>() != TypeId::of::<T1>())

            // SAFETY:
            // `TypeId` is a single field struct around `(u64, u64)` so according to the UCG it has the same layout as it
            let (a1, a2) = unsafe { mem::transmute::<_, (u64, u64)>(TypeId::of::<T1>()) };
            let (b1, b2) = unsafe { mem::transmute::<_, (u64, u64)>(TypeId::of::<T2>()) };
            assert!(a1 != b1 || a2 != b2);
        }
        // ...
    }
}

fn main() {
    <(u8, u16)>::my_fn();
    // <(u8, u8)>::my_fn(); // → evaluation of `<(u8, u8) as MyTrait>::my_fn::{constant#0}` failed
}

Or with #![feature(generic_const_exprs)] additionally so it's actually only implemented for heterogeneous tuples:
#![feature(const_type_id, generic_const_exprs)]
use std::any::TypeId;
use std::mem;
trait Homogenous<const H: bool> {}

impl<T1: 'static, T2: 'static> Homogenous<{ same_type::<T1, T2>() }> for (T1, T2) {}

const fn same_type<T1: 'static, T2: 'static>() -> bool {
    // SAFETY and reasoning see above
    let (a1, a2): (u64, u64) = unsafe { mem::transmute(TypeId::of::<T1>()) };
    let (b1, b2): (u64, u64) = unsafe { mem::transmute(TypeId::of::<T2>()) };
    a1 == b1 && a2 == b2
}

trait MyTrait {
    fn my_fn();
}

impl<T1, T2> MyTrait for (T1, T2)
where
    (T1, T2): Homogenous<false>,
{
    fn my_fn() {}
}

fn main() {
    <(u8, u16)>::my_fn();
    // <(u8, u8)>::my_fn(); // → trait bounds were not satisfied
}

